# SQL JOIN row from different table with the same values

Tags: mysql, sql-server

so i have this table

```
  code  |  name
  -----------------
  1     |  abc
  2     |  asd
  3     |  aws
```

and then i have this new table for transactional use

```
  code  | new_code
  ---------------------
  1     | 2
  2     | 3
```

i want to get the view like this below:

```
  code  |  name  |  new_code  |  name  |
  ---------------------------------------
  1     | abc    |  2         |  asd   |
  2     | asd    |  3         |  aws   |
```

what kind of query i should use for this view. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t.code, t.name, n.new_code, nt.name
FROM   this_table t
INNER JOIN new_table n   ON t.code = n.code
INNER JOIN this_table nt ON n.new_code = nt.code
```

Comment: i still have the name value in the first row

Answer (score 0):

Schema for your case.

```
        SELECT * INTO #TAB1 FROM (
        SELECT 1 CODE ,'ABC' NAME
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2,'ASD'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 3,'AWS'
        ) AS A

        SELECT * INTO #TAB2 FROM (
        SELECT  1 AS CODE, 2 AS NEW_CODE
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2,3
        )AS A
```

And below one is the solution

```
        SELECT T1.*, T2.NEW_CODE, T3.NAME FROM 
        #TAB1 T1 
        INNER JOIN #TAB2 T2 ON T1.CODE = T2.CODE
        INNER JOIN #TAB1 T3 ON T2.NEW_CODE = T3.Code
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this way

```
SELECT
    nt.code,
    (SELECT name FROM first_table where code=nt.code) AS name,
    nt.new_code,
    (SELECT name FROM first_table where code=nt.new_code) AS name
new_table nt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table1.code, table1.name, table2.new_code, table2.name
FROM   table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.code = table2.code;
```

Comment: There are two tables but only one contains name.